# Grouping earliest entry for each day using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to get my head around Linq, and at the same time keep track of the time I log on in the morning, which should be the time I get into the office thereabouts.

My code so far is:

```
EventLog SecurityLog = new EventLog("Security");

var AccountLoggedOnEntries = SecurityLog.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
    .Where(x => x.InstanceId == 4624)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        DateGenerated = x.TimeGenerated.ToShortDateString()
        ,
        TimeGenerated = x.TimeGenerated.ToShortTimeString()
        ,
        x.Message
    })
    .ToList();

DgvLogSummary.DataSource = AccountLoggedOnEntries;

DgvLogSummary.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

I want to filter the results so that I only have one entry for each day, which is the earliest time.

In SQL I would normally take the Message of the earliest entry and then group by all fields.

How do I perform a similar query in Linq?

Comment: Earliest entry? Have you tried with MIN() or MAX() in Linq?

Comment: Sort of. I don't know what I'm doing. My head is very much in SQL mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In LINQ you would group by, sort each group, and pick the first item:

```
var AccountLoggedOnEntries = log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
    .Where(x => x.InstanceId == 4624)
    .GroupBy(x => x.TimeGenerated.Date)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.TimeGenerated).First())
    .Select(x => new {
        DateGenerated = x.TimeGenerated.ToShortDateString()
    ,   TimeGenerated = x.TimeGenerated.ToShortTimeString()
    ,   x.Message
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could `GroupBy` the date and then select the minimum time

```
var AccountLoggedOnEntries = log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
    .Where(x => x.InstanceId == 4624)
    .GroupBy(x => x.TimeGenerated.Date)
    .Select(x => new {
        DateGenerated = x.Key
        , TimeGenerated = x.Min(y => y.TimeGenerated).ToShortTimeString()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Getting the appropriate `Message` is a little more tricky. One easy option is to use `x.First().Message` in the above `Select` projection.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
 var AccountLoggedOnEntries = log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
                .Where(x => x.InstanceId == 4624)
                .GroupBy(x => x.TimeGenerated.Date)
                .Select(days => days.OrderBy(time => time.TimeGenerated).FirstOrDefault())
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    DateGenerated = x.TimeGenerated.ToShortDateString()
                    ,
                    TimeGenerated = x.TimeGenerated.ToShortTimeString()
                    ,
                    x.Message
                })
                .ToList();
```